# python failing to see why class is used as argument to function to draw rectangle

Tags: python, function, class, arguments, shapes

Came across this example on a website that explains OOP. They are trying to draw canvas and rectangle and other things. In paint() method, they are passing class canvas and for the life of me, don't understand why ? Also don't seem to understand how would I draw rectangle using this code....any thoughts ??

```
class Canvas:
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.data = [[' '] * width for i in range(height)]

    def setpixel(self, row, col):
        self.data[row][col] = '*'

    def getpixel(self, row, col):
        return self.data[row][col]

    def display(self):
        print "\n".join(["".join(row) for row in self.data])

class Shape:
    def paint(self, canvas): pass

class Rectangle(Shape):
    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.w = w
        self.h = h

    def hline(self, x, y, w):
        pass

    def vline(self, x, y, h):
        pass

    def paint(self, canvas):
        hline(self.x, self.y, self.w)
        hline(self.x, self.y + self.h, self.w)
        vline(self.x, self.y, self.h)
        vline(self.x + self.w, self.y, self.h)

class CompoundShape(Shape):
    def __init__(self, shapes):
        self.shapes = shapes

    def paint(self, canvas):
        for s in self.shapes:
            s.paint(canvas)
```

Also I don't know what 'shape' class is for and how would I draw a rectangle ?? And what on earth CompoundShape is trying to do ? The code example on this website stops here without explaining anything.

Comment: It's not an argument as you're thinking. It is *inhereting* from the `Shape` class.

Comment: @Cyber I think he's talking about this: `def paint(self, canvas): pass`

Comment: Where did you find this example? `Rectangle.paint` is making calls to `hline` and `vline` instead of `self.hline`/`self.vline`, and those methods are no-ops anyway. It seems like a broken example.

Comment: Here is where I found the example. http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/object_oriented_programming.html

Answer (score 1):

The code needs to know which canvas to draw to, so you pass the canvas to the paint method.

As dano mentioned, the code is broken. It should probably contain calls like `hline(canvas, self.x, self.y, self.w)` where `hline` is a function defined outside the class.

Comment: I agree, at least in theory. The problem is the sample code doesn't actually use the `canvas` object at all. It seems like it's just bad example code.

Comment: @dano ah, I just noticed that, I was only considering the method arguments.

Comment: Thanks guys, I thought I was stupid :) Now the challenge for me is to fix this code. Can you point me to right direction ?  I have to keep the hline and vline inside the Rectangle class as it only belongs to it and somehow it has to know the coordinate inside the canvas. The setpixel and display methods work fine but don't know how would they be used for rectangle. Also don't know why the guy designed Shape class.

Answer (score 0):

class Canvas:

```
def __init__ (self, width, height):
    self.width = width
    self.height = height
    self.data = [[' '] * width for i in range(height)]


def setpixel (self, row, col):
    self.data[row][col] = '*'

def getpixel (self, row, col):
    return self.data[row][col]

def display (self):
    print "\n". join(["". join(row) for row in self.data])
```

class Shape :

```
def paint (self, canvas): pass
```

class Rectangle (Shape):

```
def __init__ (self, x, y, w, h):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.w = w
    self.h = h

def hline (self, canvas, x, y, w):
    for point in range(x,x+w):
        print x, w, point
        canvas.setpixel(y, point)    

def vline (self, canvas, x, y, h):
    for point in range(y,y+h+1):
        print y, h, point
        canvas.setpixel(point, x)    

    pass

def paint (self, canvas):
    self.hline (canvas, self.x, self.y, self.w)
    self.hline (canvas, self.x, self.y + self.h, self.w)
    self.vline (canvas, self.x, self.y, self.h)
    self.vline (canvas, self.x + self.w, self.y, self.h)
```

Comment: Please explain what you are doing. How you solved problem. Just put code is not enough.